# What cookies does Amazon use for authentication?

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, cookies

Using Chrome I'm rejecting a bunch of ad-specific cookies (by domain) and white-listing some domains to accept all cookies. I've added amazon.com and amazon.co.uk to the whitelist (including all third-party cookies) but I'm constantly being prompted to re-authenticate (i.e. I can start a message to a seller, and when hitting send get kicked out and lose the message because I have to re-authenticate).

I can't figure out what domains Amazon's authentication is coming in on to whitelist.

Comment: Sounds like it would be a lot easier to get an ad-blocker. Let a specialist do the heavy lifting.

Comment: You have perhaps blocked too many websites. Amazon uses more sites than just amazon.com and amazon.co.uk.

Comment: @harrymc yeah, I’m figuring that is the case- which is why I’m asking if anyone knows what those domains are

Comment: Basically everything that has "Amazon" in the domain should be allowed.